# How to avoid some registries within a view using sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have the following query:

```
 SELECT ue.id AS id, ue.id_padre AS id_institucion, ue.estado AS estatus, 
    iif(ue.codigo_unidad_ejecutora NOT LIKE '%SE%', 
    (c.codigo_capitulo + sc.codigo_sub_capitulo + daf.codigo_daf + ue.codigo_unidad_ejecutora), 
                             ue.codigo_unidad_ejecutora) AS estructura
                             , c.capitulo, 
                             sc.sub_capitulo, 
                             daf.daf, 
                             ue.unidad_ejecutora,
                              isnull(ue.rnc, '') AS rnc
    FROM            dbo.capitulo AS c INNER JOIN
                             dbo.sub_capitulo AS sc ON c.id = sc.id_capitulo INNER JOIN
                             dbo.daf AS daf ON daf.id_sub_capitulo = sc.id INNER JOIN
                             dbo.unidad_ejecutora AS ue ON ue.id_daf = daf.id
```

So if you see in the picture what I want is to avoid inside my column name 'Estructura' the records that start with '0999'.

**How can I set this inside my query which is a view too?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
where estructura not like '0999%'
```

Comment: This only works if estrucutra is a `string`. Which it clearly looks like one to me, but that should be noted in the question.

Comment: @gh9 - well, it's not likely to be a numeric data type since leading `0`s aren't retained in those.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree, but looking at ops karma and the simplicity of the question. I didn't think OP would know such. So i just wanted to make it sure OP knew that this only works on strings

Answer (score 0):

This will work even, because your field is a string hence the leading zeros.

I would substring the first characters starting from 1 ending at 4.

```
where substring(estructura,1,4) != '0999'
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Comment: Thank you - Added some addition comments to it :)